# Difference between RIGHT & LEFT JOIN vs RIGHT & LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join, right-join

What is the difference in results between:

1. RIGHT JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN
2. LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN ?

Can you please explain it through some examples?

Comment: Re abuses of Venn diagrams for inner vs outer join (including on this page) see my comment on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

There is no difference between `RIGHT JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. Both are the same. That means that `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same.

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx)

Comment: This is interesting. (n00b alert) Why would you need both right and left joins then? Why not just reverse the positions of your main & joined tables in your query and make do with one join direction?

Comment: Because you sometimes join more than 2 tables together and it just gives you more flexibility in how you choose to write out the query.

Comment: When you look at this image for a while and think about this, the word "join" starts to look silly and make no sense.

Comment: This is a bit confusing - it gives the impression that `A LEFT JOIN B` is the same as `A`.  Is there any difference between the excluding joins and `EXCEPT (SELECT A.* FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.Key = B.Key)`?

Comment: It is true you can get away without the right join as it can always be expressed as a left join if you reverse the tables. However, sometimes you have a complicated query written and find you need an outer join and it is sometimes simpler to use the right join rather than reorder the tables in a complicated join.

Comment: what about `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: I removed the image; according to the CodeProject license, `The Articles discussing the Work published in any form by the author may not be distributed or republished without the Author's consent.`  Unless you have the author's permission to use this image, you cannot add it to your question.

Comment: Sorry guys I don't get this, why would we have two completely different joins being equal completely? Why then the need for the different terms?

Comment: @Sizons Did you read the answer? It's 2 cases of 2 names for the same thing. It is not a case of "two completely different joins being equal completely"--which is a (redundant) contradiction in terms, so how could it be a case of that? (Rhetorical.) The names predate the programming language, "outer" is optional, clearly to allow both calling the things by their correct names & calling them by shorter names.

Answer (score 33):

Nice explanation of SQL Join:

[image]

Reference: [link](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ASQL_Joins.svg)

Comment: doesn't have names

Answer (score 25):

Here's a very nice [Visual Explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) of joins generally by our very own Jeff Atwood.  A right outer join is the same as a right join, and left join and left outer join are also the same.

Comment: He repudiates that post in its own comments. See my comment on the question (& that post) re Venn diagram abuse.

Comment: I can't find your comment.  I'm not sure 'repudiates' is the word I would choose.  It's clear that Venn diagram-type explanations don't cover several important cases though.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't see the comment by me I expected among the 208 there. But what I expected it said is what other comments of mine say, see my comment on the question here.

Comment: You don't seem to have paid attention to what my comments actually say, which is that people don't pay attention to what Venn diagram posts actually say. Eg: The circles say tableA & tableB, but under the most charitable interpretation they contain row values that are in Table A left join tableB & tableA right join tableB. Jeff's comment (#33) includes "anything that results in more rows than you originally started with does absolutely breaks the whole venn diagram concept"--that is repudiation. Moreover he's wronger than he thinks, because they break down when there aren't more rows also.

Answer (score 14):

> What is result difference between:
>
> RIGHT JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN

No difference.

> LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN ?

No difference.

Simply put, the `OUTER` keyword is optional. You can include it or omit it without affecting the resultset.

Comment: Where is this documented?