# Joins in SQL Server 2000 or 2005

Tags: sql-server, join, keyword

I am trying to understand how JOINS work on SQL Server 2000 and 2005 **SPECIFICALLY**.

In general, I understand how inner joins, left joins and right joins work.

However, all the articles that I've read, explain it with examples, but are not specific to any RDBMS. So now I am confused to the different types of joins, which are just synonyms of other joins, and which are actually different.

For e.g., 
Is **LEFT OUTER JOIN** the same as **LEFT JOIN**?
Is **RIGHT OUTER JOIN** the same as **RIGHT JOIN**?

Does SQL Server support **FULL OUTER JOIN**, **CROSS JOIN**? What are the different types of joins, and their synonyms. All these keywords are confusing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server supports [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx) and [`CROSS JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx).

And yes again, `LEFT JOIN` is a synonym for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The same applies to `RIGHT JOIN`.

In addition, `FULL JOIN` is a also a synonym for `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

You might be interested in checking out the following article by Jeff Atwood:

- [Coding Horror: A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of : [Difference between JOIN and OUTER JOIN in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183669/difference-between-join-and-outer-join-in-mysql)

There is no diffrence between Right Join and Right outer Join both are same. i.e Left Join and Left Outer Join both are same.

This will give you clear idea : 
[image]

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx)