# Get me the clear picture of outer joins in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, oracle9i, outer-join

Outer joins seem to me a little bit confusing.

Is there anyone can get me a clear picture of **outer joins** (**right, left and full**)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orginal question/answer: [**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-join-left-join-or-inner-join-or-how-to-deter/3308153#3308153**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-join-left-join-or-inner-join-or-how-to-deter/3308153#3308153)

Reading this original article on [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) will help you a lot: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Thnaks a lot Pranay.the diagram is really helpfull:-))

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article about Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins) should help you.

The special thing about Oracle Outer joins was the old notation using `(+)`, but it is obsolete now.

Answer (score 1):

The way I always think of it is:

```
LEFT JOIN - keeps all rows selected on the left  
RIGHT JOIN - keeps all rows selected on the right  
FULL JOIN - keeps all rows selected on both sides
```

Easy to keep in your head, without going to Wikipedia or drawing diagrams.

P.S. Death to Oracle + join syntax!

Answer (score 1):

I've never liked those oft seen pictures used in @Pranay Rana's answer. They show set operations but not joins. For example, the top middle picture is `A union B`, the left middle is `A except B` (or I suppose `A minus B` for Oracle), and so on.

Also consider that null does not exist in the relational model, so you can't draw a picture of it using a Venn diagrams anyway! ;)

I don't think one can draw a picture of an outer join without using tables, such as [this one](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_joinouter.htm).