# How to join 2 queries from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: The key between these 2 table is the id # of the guest.

I want to run **2 queries from 2 different tables** at the same time :

I want to create a list that a host could chek out to see every person their have ever invited. I want to show the username + location of the `guest`invited

```
 $table = query("SELECT guest FROM parties WHERE host = $uid");   

 $table2 = query("SELECT id, username, location FROM users WHERE id = $uid");
```

$uid  is the current user checking out the history of the guests their invited.

---

**parties table**

event   |  guest    |  host

xmas    |  12       |  14

---

**users table**

id    |    username   |   location

12    |    caroline   | NYC

---

How should I do that ?

Comment: Please double-check your table and column names. Is it a parties table? or members? Is `$uid` a number (12), or a name ('marc')? Did you confuse the guest and host columns in your first query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql join two table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171963/sql-join-two-table)

Comment: @jcsanyi $uid is a number (12). I just edited the name of the table. thx

Comment: You should rethink your data structure a little.  It appears to me that only way to achieve what are asking is to join user.username to parties.host (as in the answer by @Daniel)  Treating a person's name as a key in this way is a very bad practice. What if two people have the same name?  They will see each other's data! What if someone wants to change their name in the system? They will lose all their old data.  Consider a unique number for the key instead.

Comment: The key is a unique id : see above, i edited my question. the id 12 is the link between the 2 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = query('SELECT `u`.`username`, `u`.`location` FROM `users` u JOIN `parties` p ON `p`.`guest` = `u`.`id` WHERE `p`.`host` = ' . $uid)
```

Comment: should i replace all the Ps with parties and the Us with users ?

Comment: You could - it's your choose but it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: could you please review my question again ? I edited it. The unique key between the two table is the id (12) .

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you run 2 query at the same time.
But you can use this if you want getting result in one variable

```
$query = SELECT id, username, location FROM users
LEFT JOIN parties 
ON users.host = parties.host
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you need to do is to use the JOIN clause. I hope the below code helps out:
$sql = ("SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`location`, `parties`.`guest` JOIN USING (id) WHERE `id` = '$uid'");
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die('Failed to perform query: ' . mysql_error);