# SQL ,How to connect two IDs with name in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables.

FIRST Table "Player" contains:

```
Player_id;
Name;
Surname;
```

SECOND Table "Substitutions" contains:

```
Sub_id;
In_player_id;
Out_player_id;
```

And now i want to print name and surname of `in_player_id` and of `out_player_id` using `select` in `sql` language

Comment: This is a pretty basic `join`, just do it to the `player` table twice.  What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join two table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171963/sql-join-two-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using two `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT INPLAYER.Name, INPLAYER.Surname, OUTPLAYER.Name, OUTPLAYER.Surname
FROM Substitutions
INNER JOIN Player AS INPLAYER ON (Substitutions.In_player_id = INPLAYER.Player_id)
INNER JOIN Player AS OUTPLAYER ON (Substitutions.Out_player_id = OUTPLAYER.Player_id)
```

For Oracle database remove the "AS" keyword.

Comment: It says "missing kewords" something near "AS" in 3 line

Comment: @sgeddes works fine for me in sql server management studio 2012. are you sure all table and column names and parantheses are correct?