# how to write this sql

Tags: sql

I have one table : SCORE

```
name score
mike 97
tom  86
lucy 44
```

and another table : RANK

```
low up rank
90 100 A 
80 90 B
70 80 C
60 70 D
0 60 E
```

and I want the result like that

```
name score rank 
mike 97     A
tom  86     B
lucy 44     E
```

How to write sql

Comment: Do a JOIN. Check value between low and up as condition.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve]. And please use a search engine of your choice before asking questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join two table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171963/sql-join-two-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query, `JOIN` two table with condition of `rank` between `low` and `up`

```
SELECT name,score,rank
FROM    score
    JOIN rank ON score > low AND score<=up
```