# write a subquery - to get info from same table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table as below. I want to write a query that displays the parent name and other child info for each child.

```
|    ID     |  Name   |  ParentID  |
|-----------|---------|------------|
|  Parent1  |  aaa    |            |
|  Parent2  |  bbb    |            |
|  Child1   |  ccc    |  Parent1   |
|  Child2   |  ddd    |  Parent1   |
|  Parent3  |  eee    |            |
```

I want to display the details as below:

```
|    ID     |  Name   |  ParentID  | ParentName |
|-----------|---------|------------|------------|
| Parent1   |  aaa    |            |            | 
| Parent2   |  bbb    |            |            | 
| Child1    |  xxx    |  Parent1   |  aaa       |
| Child2    |  yyy    |  Parent1   |  aaa       |
| Parent3   |  ccc    |            |            |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join two table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171963/sql-join-two-table)

Comment: Sounds like query with self-joins, that is, joining a table to itself. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-06.html and http://www.databasedev.co.uk/self-join_query.html

Comment: The self join info is great! It resolved my question. Thanks!!!