# Get data from tables

Tags: php, mysql

How can I join two tables? Where I can get the product name, product image and product desc in tblproduct, and product_stocks, product_price and product_size in tblproduct_extension?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT tblproduct.product_image
   , tblproduct.product_name
   , tblproduct_extension.product_price
   , tblproduct.product_desc
   , tblproduct_extension.product_stocks
INNER JOIN tblproduct_extension
ON tblproduct.id=tblproduct_extension.product_id;
```

Table: [tblproduct_extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoIeQ.png) [tblproduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXgjU.png)

Comment: Show us your database schema please

Comment: How about `select * from tab1 join tab2 on <condition>`?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, please try to search it on google. There are millions of example of joining two table. Read [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) for better understanding

Comment: To save googling for anybody who comes here in future, syntax is `SELECT <data> FROM <table> INNER JOIN <other table> ON <conditions>;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171963/sql-join-two-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` so only products that match in the `tblproduct` will be selected:

```
SELECT * FROM `tblproduct`
    LEFT JOIN `tblproduct_extension`
    ON `tblproduct`.`id` = `tblproduct_extension`.`product_id`;
```

**Edit**

If you want to get it using ID (using your example):

```
//GET PRODUCT DETAILS
$id = $_GET['view_product'];

$search_query = "SELECT * FROM `tblproduct`
    LEFT JOIN `tblproduct_extension`
    ON `tblproduct`.`id` = `tblproduct_extension`.`product_id`
    WHERE `tblproduct`.`id` = ".$id."";
```

Comment: What if I get the product information base on id? This is my code but it's not working.

//GET PRODUCT DETAILS
$id = $_GET['view_product'];
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension ON tblproduct.id=tblproduct_extension.id WHERE id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);

Comment: I've updated my answer, you just need to add a conditional `WHERE` clause at the end...

Comment: Thanks!! Godbless you.

Comment: Hey. How can I get the product size for each product? 
Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u08eI.png

$id = $_GET['view_product'];
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension ON tblproduct.id=tblproduct_extension.product_id WHERE tblproduct.id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Size</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['product_size'];?>"><?php echo $row['product_size'];?></option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fields
FROM table
INNER JOIN 
another_table ON 
condition
```