# sql result of two table

Tags: sql, mariadb

i want result of two table when i do a select,

first table A :

```
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |
```

second table B :

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |          0.03   |
```

i want this result:

```
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |          0.03   |
```

thanks for any response

Comment: Hint: `JOIN` ...

Comment: Why do both tables have a time column, with the same values?!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join two table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171963/sql-join-two-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(INNER) JOIN is what you need

```
select a.CID, a.time, step , time_in_seconde,cpu    
from tab a join tab b 
             on a.cid=b.cid
```

Just to add some 'visual' explanations of joins:
[image: Joins]

Answer (score 0):

Use `inner` join like below

```
select a.cid,a.time,a.step,a.time_in_second,b.cpu 
from t1 a 
inner join t2 b
on a.cid=b.cid
```