# How do I query multiple tables using inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Given the table creation SQL and insertion SQL, How will I generate a query to display the information in a a particular way?

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
   id serial NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
   iname varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE suburbs (
    id serial NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    icity integer REFERENCES cities (id), 
    iname varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
CREATE TABLE type (
   id serial NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
   iname varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
CREATE TABLE sale (
   id serial NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
   iname varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE estate (
    id serial NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    icity integer REFERENCES cities (id),
    isuburb integer REFERENCES suburbs (id),
    itype integer REFERENCES type (id),
    isale integer REFERENCES sale (id),
    idescription text,
    itimestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)

INSERT INTO cities (iname) VALUES ('Johannesburg');
INSERT INTO suburbs (icity, iname) VALUES (1, 'Westbury');
INSERT INTO type (iname) VALUES ('Room');
INSERT INTO sale (iname) VALUES ('Rent');

INSERT INTO estate (icity, isuburb, itype, isale, idescription) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 'A Nice place in a real bad neighbor hood');
```

Now I want the numerical values that are in the table estate to be displayed by the string values that they represent.

E.G
1 Johannesburg, Westbury, Room, Rent, Description

What will the SQL Query be for this, I am more concerned in using postgreSQL.

Comment: Literally **all of the values**, like every single column? And is this MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: You want to do a `JOIN` on all columns from each table?  Any reason you want to do that?

Comment: @Yuck I'm converting from using mysql to postgreSQL so it will be postgreSQL, Well certain values, from each table some of the tables are used as reference tables.

Comment: You should post the table definitions or at least the columns involved in matching then if you want more meaningful answers.

Comment: What have you tried, and what result do you get?  Where EXACTLY are you stuck?

Comment: Just a heads-up that your `cities` and `suburbs` tables are not normalized with respect to `estate`. As `estate` can refer directly to both a city and a suburb, and suburb is already contained in a city according to your table defs.

Comment: @Yuck thank you I was looking for that word normalization.

Comment: SELECT estate.id, cities.iname, suburbs.iname FROM estate INNER JOIN cities  ON estate.icity = cities.id INNER JOIN estate  estate.iname ON suburbs.id;

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, they must have some sort of common field. Let's assume the common field between them is called `<tablename>_ID`; the way you do it is as follows:

```
select A.colx, A.coly, A.colz, B.colx, B.colw, c.cold 
from A inner join B on A.ID=B.A_ID 
     inner join C on C.A_ID=A.ID
```

Answer (score 15):

you cany try like

```
select * from table1  
inner join table2 on tabl1.pk = table2.FK 
inner join table3 on tabl1.pk = table.FK
```

Final

```
select table2.iname,table3.iname,table4.iname,table1.idescription 
from estate  as table1 
inner join sale  as table2 on table1.isale = table2.id 
inner join  type  as table3 on table1.itype  = table3.id 
inner join  suburbs  as table3 on table1.isuburb = table3.id 
inner join  cities as table4 on table1.icity = table4.id
```

If you want to get info about joins have look to below image

[image]
Ans at : [How do I decide when to use right joins/left joins or inner joins Or how to determine which table is on which side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-joins-left-joins-or-inner-joins-or-how-to-dete/3308153#3308153)

Answer (score 2):

```
select suburbs.icity
        , cities.iname
        , suburbs.iname
        , type.iname
        , sale.iname
        , estate.idescription
from estate
inner join suburbs on suburbs.id = estate.isuburb
inner join cities on cities.id = estate.icity
inner join type on type.id = estate.itype
inner join sale on sale.id = estate.isale
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are looking for a **join..**

```
select ct.iname as CityName,sb.name as SuburbName,et.*
from estate et
join cities ct on ct.id=et.icity
join suburbs sb on sb.id=et.isuburb
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
ON B.id = A.b
INNER JOIN C
ON C.id = A.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example as per ur ques.

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,C.*
FROM A , B, C
WHERE C.c = B.b
  AND B.b = A.a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -> select * from estate
 -> inner join cities on estate.icity=cities.id
 -> inner join suburbs on estate.isuburb=suburbs.id
 -> inner join type on estate.itype=type.id
 -> inner join sale on estate.isale=sale.id;
```