# Mysql: Select with Left Join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I have a query of the following type:

```
select * from tbl_1 where [cond] as aliasA LEFT JOIN tbl_2 as aliasB 
 ON (aliasA.id = aliasB.id) WHERE aliasB.id IS NULL
```

It appears that it's working except that it's ignoring the last `WHERE aliasB.id IS NULL`.
So, it's just returning the results of:

```
select * from tbl_1 where cond as aliasA LEFT JOIN tbl_2 as aliasB 
 ON (aliasA.id = aliasB.id)
```

How would I change the above query to get
the results of querying tbl_1 where [cond] displaying only the rows that are not in tbl_2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted and upvote it if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_1 aliasA LEFT JOIN tbl_2 aliasB
ON aliasA.id = aliasB.id
WHERE condA 
  AND aliasB.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

`aliasB.id = NULL` will always be false. The correct way is `aliasB.id IS NULL` or the uglier MySQL-specific `aliasB.id <=> NULL`

Comment: You're correct. Unfortunately, I meant to say IS NULL (which is how my code is written) but the results are as I said (not giving me what I want). I edited my post, correcting the IS NULL portion.

Comment: Then I think you should try and move the first condition to the `WHERE` clause after the join, like Marco writes.

Answer (score 6):

Orignal Ans at : [How do I decide when to use right joins/left joins or inner joins Or how to determine which table is on which side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-joins-left-joins-or-inner-joins-or-how-to-dete/3308153#3308153)

Best way i found is have look to below image clear out you doubt

Check the case 1 and 2 in image will give you your answer

and change you where condition to `WHERE aliasB.id is NULL`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

You need to use "IS NULL" instead of "= NULL"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IS NULL` to check for NULL values, not `= NULL`:

```
WHERE aliasB.id IS NULL
```