# Output rows in one table for which no match exists in another

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables: `scans` and `personel`. In `scans` there is a column `createdby` where the username of the person who created a scan is there. I need to create a view where to see these scans but instead of the username, I want to see the full name of that person which I have in the table `personel`. This query mostly works:

```
select personel.firstname ||' '|| personel.lastname as CREATEDBY
from scans inner join personel on scans.createdby = personel.username;
```

The problem is that there are some user names in `scans.createdby` which aren't anymore in the `personel` table and their scans are not retrieved by the above query since the values in the `createdby` column does not match with any value in the `username` column.

So for that case, I would like to output the value from `createdby` for those scans.

So if:

`scans.createdby = personel.username` =>  show  full name

but if:

`scans.createdby` doesn't match any `personel.username` =>  show username from `scans.createdby` instead of full name

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3308153/173497) to the SO question [mysql - How do I decide when to use right joins/left joins or inner joins Or how to determine which table is on which side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-joins-left-joins-or-inner-joins-or-how-to-dete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ifnull(personel.firstname + ' ' + personel.lastname, scan.createdby) as CREATEDBY
from scans 
LEFT join personel on scans.createdby = personel.username;
```

Comment: well actually for the last version I get empty entries when there is no usernsme. Before revision was just fine :)
Also had to use  NVL function for oracle instead of ISNULL, but this is my bad that i didn't specified before.  Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You want a left join from `scans` to `personel` and you should use a coalesce operator (e.g. `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` in SQL Server) or function to create the `CREATEDBY` column in your query result.

Answer (score 2):

```
select case when personel.username is null then scans.createdby else personel.firstname ||' '|| personel.lastname end as CREATEDBY
from scans left outer join personel on scans.createdby = personel.username;
```