# Understanding LEFT JOIN inner working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have gone through many online tutorials, even **[Jeff's article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)** on SQL joins and I think I still don't understand properly how SQL joins work internally. For example, let us consider the following scenario.

I have 2 tables `TableA` and `TableB` and some dummy data.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(500),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE TableB(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(500),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO TableA(name) VALUES('A');
INSERT INTO TableA(name) VALUES('B');
INSERT INTO TableA(name) VALUES('C');
INSERT INTO TableA(name) VALUES('D');

INSERT INTO TableB(name) VALUES('x');
INSERT INTO TableB(name) VALUES('A');
INSERT INTO TableB(name) VALUES('Y');
INSERT INTO TableB(name) VALUES('C');
```

### TableA:

[image]

### Table B:

[image]

Now I am running the following query:

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableA.name, TableB.id, TableB.name
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name=TableB.name;
```

which gives me the output:

[image]

### Question:

How exactly the data is being compared *internally*, retrieved and the resulting table populated?

Comment: would it be easier to understand if you saw the implicit join version of the same query? `select * from tablea, tableb where tablea.name = tableb.name` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, or in particular what your emphasis on "internally" signifies.  If you are inquiring into details of MySQL's implementation, then a MySQL-specific venue would probably be a better choice than SO.

Comment: @John - I mean how exactly the comparison takes place in MySQL(since that is the one I am using)? Is the comparison logic(cartesian product?) different for different RDBMS's? Since I don't understand the concept properly, may be I phrased it incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Reading this original article on The [Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project) will help you a lot: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

[image]

Also check this post: [SQL SERVER – Better Performance – LEFT JOIN or NOT IN](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/)?.

Find original one at: [Difference between JOIN and OUTER JOIN in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-joins-left-joins-or-inner-joins-or-how-to-dete/3308153#3308153).

Answer (score 0):

When you do a left join, you will get at least one row back for each row in the table on the left hand side regardless of whether there is a corresponding row in the table on the right hand side.  When there isn't a corresponding row on the right hand side, the values in the resulting  table will be null for those columns.

When you change the left join to an inner join, you will not get the left hand rows rows back.  That is because the join condition must be true.

It might be helpful to alias the column names so you know which ones come from tablea and which ones come from table b.  Once you try that, remove the left keyword and try it again.  I hope that will be helpful.

```
SELECT TableA.id TABA_ID, TableA.name TABA_NAME, 
       TableB.id TABB_ID, TableB.name TABB_NAME
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name=TableB.name;
```