# How do I know which table is left and right mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I know the first select from query is the left table, but I am still confused when to use right and left join:

ex:

```
select chann.name from investments inv
right join channels chann on chann.id = inv.channel_id;


select chann.name from channels chann
left join investments inv on chann.id = inv.channel_id;
```

They both return the same result, why in first query is used right and why left on second one, Does this have to do with Foreign Key something?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-joins-left-joins-or-inner-joins-or-how-to-dete

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: A left join B is the same as B right join A. But humans usually find it much harder to understand right join. That's why most people use left join only.

Comment: This may help you to understand the difference in SQL joins: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example both query are the same, because when change right to left you also change tables order. For simple understanding this, consider follow example:

```
SELECT A.* FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B on A.key=B.Key
```

In this case, LEFT JOIN means all records from Table1, because is the table in the left. If you use right means all records from table 2

Comment: What does "in the left" mean? Do you mean to the left of the join statement "LEFT JOIN"? To what does the positionality right or left relate?

Comment: @fraxtureWhen you use `FROM TableA`, that's your starting point located on the LEFT, any other joined table that comes later is on the RIGHT...

Answer (score 1):

> LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows
>   from the right table 
>   RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table,
>   and the matched rows from the left table

Meaning that a left join will take all the records from your first table and join them only with the records on the right table that adhere to your ON condition
A right join will do the oposite (take all from second table and join with only records on first table that adhere to ON condition)