# SQL query-Count(*) with a condition

Tags: mysql

So I am a beginner at SQL and I am stuck with this query: 
"For event requests, list the event number, event date (eventrequest.dateheld), and count of the event plans.  **Only include event requests in the result if the event request has more than one related event plan with a work date in December 2013."**

The tables are:

```
EVENTREQUEST{EVENTNO(PK),DATEHELD}

EVENTPLAN{PLANO(PK), EVENTNO(FK), WORKDATE}
```

I have written this query so far but I dont know how to proceed, I mean how will we count the number of event plans with workdate in December 2013? Please help!

```
    Select EVENTNO, EVENTREQUEST.DATEHELD, COUNT(*) 
    from EVENTREQUEST, EVENTPLAN
    where EVENTREQUEST.EVENTNO = EVENTPLAN.EVENTNO;
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server ???

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as PLANS, EVENTREQUEST.EVENTNO, DATEHELD
FROM EVENTREQUEST LEFT JOIN EVENTPLAN
ON EVENTREQUEST.EVENTNO = EVENTPLAN.EVENTNO
WHERE EVENTPLAN.WORKDATE BETWEEN '2015-11-30' AND '2015-12-30';
```

Comment: Can you please explain what count(1) does? I have'nt studied this yet, and also is it possible to solve this query with the inner join? and I also don't get "WHERE EVENTPLAN.WORKDATE BETWEEN '2015-11-30' AND '2015-12-30". Can we not use where tochar(workdate, 'MON-YY') = 'DEC-2013'?

Comment: Count(*) and Count(1) have an equal result but Count(1) is optimized. you just want the count you don't need to select * and then count the records.

Comment: In order to understand the different between join, I suggest you to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-joins-left-joins-or-inner-joins-or-how-to-dete/3308153#3308153

Comment: @hedeshy MSSQL and MySQL are both smart enough to recognise both Count(*) and Count(1) for what they are, and optimise them. They don't read all columns just to count them.

Comment: @Cylindric You are probably right about MSSQL but in mysql it depends on the engine you use. For a concrete example, let's say we're trying to paginate a query. If you have a query SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5,10, let's say, running SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users LIMIT 5,10 is essentially free with MyISAM but takes the same amount of time as the first query with InnoDB.