# WHERE keyword is not working in inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have used `WHERE user_contact_info.master_admin = 1` in `$users_list1` but its not working. I am also used `AND user_contact_info.master_admin = 1` but its not working. `$users_list2` works without inner join. How can I fix `$users_list1` sql? Thanks!

**SQL 1**

```
$users_list1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT 
                user_contact_info.id, 
                user_contact_info.user_name, 
                user_contact_info.user_title, 
                user_contact_info.user_direct, 
                user_contact_info.user_mobile, 
                user_contact_info.user_mail_address, 
                user_contact_info.user_email, 
                user_contact_info.master_admin, 
                company_info.com_name
                FROM user_contact_info 
                INNER JOIN company_info 
                ON user_contact_info.user_company = company_info.id WHERE user_contact_info.master_admin = 1 
                ORDER BY company_info.com_name ASC 
                limit  $offset, $limit" );
```

**SQL 2**

```
$users_list2 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from user_contact_info WHERE master_admin = 1 ORDER BY user_name ASC limit  $offset, $limit" )
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not working? It shows any error? or is expected result not met?

Comment: check if really user info table has child records for company info table

Comment: Is there record in your DB for that particular INNER JOIN? 

This link explains meaning of different of joins for SQL query:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308122/how-do-i-decide-when-to-use-right-joins-left-joins-or-inner-joins-or-how-to-dete/3308153#3308153