# Outer join or full join is possible in mysql laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Outer join or full join is possible in MySQL Laravel?

Comment: Outer join example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481321/how-to-do-a-left-outer-join-with-laravel. Also check out documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Comment: Which outer join?

Answer (score 0):

Lavarel does implement `leftJoin` (which I suppose is what you mean by *outer join*), as [described in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) - see section *Left Join / Right Join Clause*.

`full join` is not supported in MySQL, nor in Lavarel.