# How can I do a self-join based on a related column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this table:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+---------+
| id | related |  color  |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | NULL    | red     |
| 2  | 1       | blue    |
| 3  | NULL    | green   |
| 4  | 1       | white   |
| 5  | 3       | brown   |
| 6  | NULL    | gray    |
| 7  | 3       | black   |
| 8  | 1       | orange  |
| 9  | 6       | pink    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I have an `id` number and I need to get the color of related `id`.

Here is some examples:

```
$id = 4; // I need to get `red`
$id = 5; // I need to get `green`
$id = 6; // I need to get `gray`
$id = 9; // I need to get `gray`
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT t2.color FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.related = t2.id WHERE t1.id = :id
```

It works for almost all rows and it returns expected color. Just it doesn't work for those rows which have `NULL` related. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to associate the related colors to the id in the related column.  In cases where there is no related color, the `COALESCE()` will return the primary color.

```
SELECT t.id, COALESCE(r.color,t.color) AS color
FROM myTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable r ON r.id = t.related
WHERE t.id = :id
```

---

Here is the `INNER JOIN` query for comparison.  You'll see that you lose the rows where the related id is `NULL`, which I don't believe is what you want.

```
SELECT t.id, COALESCE(r.color,t.color) AS color
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN myTable r ON r.id = t.related
WHERE t.id = :id
```

Comment: Ah, I understand `ISNULL()`. But why `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? What's wring with `JOIN`?

Comment: Also your query doesn't what `WHERE` clause ..! Why?

Comment: the syntax for left join doesn't need a where clause unless you're specifying a particular subset. This will get all rows.

Comment: How does it not work.  And the reason for left outer is in the event that the equijoin between id and related doesn't exist.

Comment: You need `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`. Or `IFNULL`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `ISNULL()` Besides, that `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows. I just need one row and one column. In other word I just need to get one record containing a color name.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are right .. `ISNULL` isn't correct and it should be replace with either `IFNULL` of `COALESCE` ..! But still result isn't what I need ...

Comment: My last question. what's the difference between `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: @stack - [it's the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183669/difference-between-join-and-outer-join-in-mysql).  I've always preferred the explicit `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @devlincarnate I see, thank you .. just as a note, you were right, I need a `LEFT` not `INNER` join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c1.id as id,
  IFNULL(c2.color, c1.color) as color
FROM colors c1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN colors c2
  ON c1.related = c2.id;
```

Check [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa6afc/2/0) with a demo.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, just what's `OUTER` ? Why not just `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @stack In the case of mysql I think there is no difference, IIRC its an ANSI-SQL standard convention but you can omit it. A simple left join would do. The most common join is an "INNER" join where you want records that intersect given a key, so think of an OUTER as an opposite of that. Now, you still want all records from the LEFT regardless so you are basically saying "take everything on the LEFT and try to match it with the right, if there is no coincidence for a record, leave the OUTER record as null but still return the LEFT.