# 'Group by' calculations don't match expected results

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
select product_name, (sum(item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS product_total
from products inner join order_items 
using(product_id) 
group by product_name
```

My query's output:

[image: My query's output]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

I got almost everything to display but `Gibson Les Paul` `product_total` is wrong and the last row doesn't show the N`ull` with its `product_total`.

Comment: update your question and show your related  table schema  ..

Comment: ("The `NULL`" is funny, anyway - product with id, but without name? *outer* join?)

Comment: @greybeard i thought that at first, but it was a rollup value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inner join means that you will only see order_items that have a product_name.  Use an outer join to see order_items that do not have a product_name. Also, your `sum` should be the outer most function. Maybe something like:

```
select product_name, sum((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS product_total
from order_items left join products 
  on order_items.product_id=products.product_id
group by product_name
```

If needed, look up an explanation of inner and outer joins, [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183669/difference-between-join-and-outer-join-in-mysql) for example.

But, looking a little closer at your data, the type of join is probably not the issue for the `null` row. The bottom row is merely a total of all the other rows, so adding [with rollup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) after the group by clause would give you that row.

Comment: That produces the same output as my query

Comment: Perhaps give us a sample of data from the two tables including rows where product name is null.

Comment: I've updated my answer with rollup and changing the position of the function.

Comment: I believe the 'Null' is the sum of Product_total not sure how to incorporate that

Comment: using `with rollup`