# Laravel multiple count on multiple join

Tags: laravel

i have four table  socket , office , container, project i need to join these table with primey table soket and add count in each table group by socket.id .

```php
$data['socjetsreport'] = DB::table('socket')
    ->limit(5)
    ->join('attached', 'attached.socket_id', '=', 'socket.id', 'left outer')
    ->join('office', 'office.socket_id', '=', 'socket.id', 'left outer')
    ->join('container', 'container.socket_id', '=', 'socket.id', 'left outer')
    ->join('project', 'project.socket_id', '=', 'socket.id', 'left outer')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'socket.employee_id', 'left outer')
    ->select('socket.id as id', 'socket.name as name',  'users.name as uname', 
        DB::raw("count(attached.socket_id) as attccount"))
    ->groupBy('socket.id')
    ->get();
```

I try to apply it in MySQL query and it run well but in laravel it just give me wrong count.

This is my MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    users.name,
    COUNT(*) AS attached,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM socket
        LEFT OUTER JOIN container ON socket.id = container.socket_id
        WHERE socket.id = @id
    ) AS container,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM socket
        LEFT OUTER JOIN project ON socket.id = project.socket_id
        WHERE socket.id = @id
    ) AS project, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM socket
        LEFT OUTER JOIN office ON socket.id = office.socket_id
        WHERE socket.id = @id
    ) AS office 
FROM socket
LEFT OUTER JOIN attached ON socket.id = attached.socket_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON socket.employee_id = users.id WHERE socket.id = @id
GROUP BY users.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [LEFT OUTER JOIN is the same as LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183669/difference-between-right-left-join-vs-right-left-outer-join-in-sql/3183687#3183687) you could just use the query builder's `leftJoin()` method.

For all the subqueries in your `SELECT` statement, you should use the query builder's `selectSub()` method.

> ```php
>     /**
>      * Add a subselect expression to the query.
>      *
>      * @param  \Closure|\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|string  $query
>      * @param  string  $as
>      * @return $this
>      *
>      * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
>      */
>     public function selectSub($query, $as)
>     {
>         [$query, $bindings] = $this->createSub($query);
>
>         return $this->selectRaw(
>             '('.$query.') as '.$this->grammar->wrap($as), $bindings
>         );
>     }
> ```

The resulting query looks like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

$data['socjetsreport'] = DB::table('socket')
    ->select('users.name')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as attached')
    ->selectSub(
        function (Builder $query) use ($socketId) {
            return $query->selectRaw('count(*)')->from('socket')
                         ->leftJoin('container', 'socket.id', 'container.socket_id')
                         ->where('socket.id', $socketId);
        },
        'container'
    )
    ->selectSub(
        function (Builder $query) use ($socketId) {
            return $query->selectRaw('count(*)')->from('socket')
                         ->leftJoin('project', 'socket.id', 'project.socket_id')
                         ->where('socket.id', $socketId);
        },
        'project'
    )
    ->selectSub(
        function (Builder $query) use ($socketId) {
            return $query->selectRaw('count(*)')->from('socket')
                         ->leftJoin('office', 'socket.id', 'office.socket_id')
                         ->where('socket.id', $socketId);
        },
        'office'
    )
    ->leftJoin('attached', 'socket.id', 'attached.socket_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'socket.employee_id', 'users.id')
    ->where('socket.id', $socketId)
    ->groupBy('users.name')
    ->get();
```

Or like this if you are hung up on using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

$data['socjetsreport'] = DB::table('socket')
    ->select('users.name')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as attached')
    ->selectSub(
        function (Builder $query) use ($socketId) {
            return $query->selectRaw('count(*)')->from('socket')
                         ->join('container', 'socket.id', '=', 'container.socket_id', 'left outer')
                         ->where('socket.id', $socketId);
        },
        'container'
    )
    ->selectSub(
        function (Builder $query) use ($socketId) {
            return $query->selectRaw('count(*)')->from('socket')
                         ->join('project', 'socket.id', '=', 'project.socket_id', 'left outer')
                         ->where('socket.id', $socketId);
        },
        'project'
    )
    ->selectSub(
        function (Builder $query) use ($socketId) {
            return $query->selectRaw('count(*)')->from('socket')
                         ->join('office', 'socket.id', '=', 'office.socket_id', 'left outer')
                         ->where('socket.id', $socketId);
        },
        'office'
    )
    ->join('attached', 'socket.id', '=', 'attached.socket_id', 'left outer')
    ->join('users', 'socket.employee_id', '=', 'users.id', 'left outer')
    ->where('socket.id', $socketId)
    ->groupBy('users.name')
    ->get();
```

PHP 7.4's shorthand closures can make those selectSub statements look a bit smaller

```php
    ->selectSub(
        fn(Builder $query) => $query->selectRaw('count(*)')->from('socket')
                                    ->leftJoin('container', 'socket.id', 'container.socket_id')
                                    ->where('socket.id', $socketId),
        'container'
    )
```

You can try checking the SQL for yourself by replacing `->get()` with `toSql()` and dumping the result.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by using this query

```
$socjetsreport  = DB::table('socket')
    ->select("socket.id", "socket.name", 
    DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(id) AS attchedcount FROM attached WHERE attached.socket_id=socket.id) as attchedcount"), 
    DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(id) AS officecount FROM office WHERE office.socket_id=socket.id) as officecount"),
    DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(id) AS containercount FROM container WHERE container.socket_id=socket.id) as containercount"),
    DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(id) AS projectcount FROM project WHERE project.socket_id=socket.id) as projectcount"),
    DB::raw("(SELECT users.name AS employname FROM users WHERE users.id=socket.employee_id) as employname")
    )
    ->orderBy('socket.id', 'asc')
    ->get();
```